# How to move a rectangle in x and y pixels position with tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

I want to move my rectangle at specific x and y pixels and not add to it like this function `tkinter.Canvas.move`. I want to specify an absolute coordinate (x, y) in which my rectangle should placed in. This image will explain. Thanks!

[This Image explains every thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTKFt.png)

This is test code but it's add to x and y not assign to it:

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('press Enter to ASSIGN ')
font_mid = ("arial", 15)
c = Canvas()
c.pack()
def move(x, y):
    c.move(rect, x, y)

rect = c.create_rectangle(50, 50, 100, 100, fill='red', activeoutline='orange')


Label(root, text='X:          ', bg='red', fg="white", font=font_mid).place(x=10,y=10)
x_ent = Entry(root, bd=0, font=font_mid)
x_ent.place(x=35, y=12, width=55)


Label(root, text='Y:          ', bg='green', fg="white", font=font_mid).place(x=100,y=10)
y_ent = Entry(root, bd=0, font=font_mid)
y_ent.place(x=125, y=12, width=55)

x_ent.bind('<Return>', lambda i: move(int(x_ent.get()), int(y_ent.get())))
y_ent.bind('<Return>', lambda i: move(int(x_ent.get()), int(y_ent.get())))

root.mainloop()
```

Thanks.

Comment: plz help if you know how i want it

Comment: I think what are you searching for is the `coords` [method](https://www.i-programmer.info/programming/python/5105-creating-the-python-ui-with-tkinter-the-canvas-widget.html).

Comment: Use `moveto()` instead of `move()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i can understand, you want to move the rectangle in a specific area of the window [as shown in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YRFs.png).

For this result, you can add a fix number to the y value so it never goes out of that area.

**You can try this:**

```
def move(x, y):
    c.moveto(rect, x, y+45)
```

You may want to restrict the negative value or it will move out.

Hope you were looking for this.

Comment: sorry but I want the rectangle only how ? @EzyGrip

Comment: Then you can use `.moveto()`

`def move(x,y):
    c.moveto(rect, x, y)`

@ZOStudio

Comment: it's the same as `move()` @EzyGrip

Comment: `move()`  and `moveto()` are two different things.  `move()` adds the given x and y value to previous x and y value, whereas `moveto()` replaces the previous value with the given value. You can conform this by giving x=0 and y=0 to both of them. `move()` will do nothing(_As it will add 0 to previous x and y value which will give the same value of x and y_), where as `moveto()` will set the position of the rectangle to x=0 and y=0 and set it at top-left corner of the window.

Comment: but it's the samw when I use `moveto(x, y)` can u edit the question and explain for me please in my case can you please made a 2D viewport with that rect move at x and y @EzyGrip

Comment: Try the new edited answer, hope you were looking for this. @ZOStudio